# Populate lists by their categories and their sub elements

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'd like to display a list of meal categories (i.e : Italian Food, Chinese Food, etc) and their respective sub lists of meals (i.e : Pizza -> Part of Italian food List, Noodles -> part of Chinese food List).

Im using tuples but I'm having trouble doing the above. Thank you in advance.

**Here is my mock data**

```
// MOCK DATA FOR NOW!!
class FoodListViewModel {
    var meals: [Meal] = []
    var mealCategories = [(String, Meal)]()
    
    init() {
        // Initiate the model (Meal) in here
        fetchFood()
    }
    
    func fetchFood() {
        let meal1 = Meal(id: 1, name: "Fettucine", imageName: "linguine", rating: 4, description: "Delicious Fettucine Linguine with a side of basil", price: 20.10, category: "italian")
        let meal2 = Meal(id: 2, name: "Linguine", imageName: "linguine", rating: 4, description: "Delicious Fettucine Linguine with a side of basil", price: 20.10, category: "italian")
        let meal3 = Meal(id: 3, name: "Spaghetti", imageName: "linguine", rating: 4, description: "Delicious Fettucine Linguine with a side of basil", price: 20.10, category: "italian")
        let meal4 = Meal(id: 4, name: "Pesto", imageName: "linguine", rating: 4, description: "Delicious Fettucine Linguine with a side of basil", price: 20.10, category: "italian")
        let meal5 = Meal(id: 5, name: "Noodles", imageName: "linguine", rating: 4, description: "Delicious Chao Ming with a side of basil", price: 20.10, category: "chinese")
        let meal6 = Meal(id: 6, name: "Spicy Noodles", imageName: "linguine", rating: 4, description: "Delicious Chao Ming with a side of basil", price: 20.10, category: "chinese")
        let meal7 = Meal(id: 7, name: "Tacos", imageName: "linguine", rating: 4, description: "Delicious Chao Ming with a side of basil", price: 20.10, category: "mexican")
        
        
        meals.append(meal1)
        meals.append(meal2)
        meals.append(meal3)
        meals.append(meal4)
        meals.append(meal5)
        meals.append(meal6)
        meals.append(meal7)
        
        mealCategories.append(("italian", meal1))
        mealCategories.append(("italian", meal2))
        mealCategories.append(("italian", meal3))
        mealCategories.append(("italian", meal4))
        mealCategories.append(("chinese", meal5))
        mealCategories.append(("mexican", meal6))
    }
}
```

Meal class

```
struct Meal: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var imageName: String
    var rating: Int
    var description: String
    var price: Double
    var category: String
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, imageName: String, rating: Int, description: String, price: Double, category: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.imageName = imageName
        self.rating = rating
        self.description = description
        self.price = price
        self.category = category
    }
}
```

**And here is where a rough idea of how i would like to display it**

```
struct FoodListView: View {
    var viewModel: FoodListViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(viewModel.mealCategories.key) { category in
                    Text("\(category)")
                        // Display list of meals (values) associated with this category (key) here
                        meals // 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension FoodListView {
    var meals: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(viewModel.mealCategories.value) { meal in
                        NavigationLink(destination: FoodDetailView(viewModel: FoodDetailViewModel(meal: meal))) {
                            FoodListRowView(viewModel: FoodListRowViewModel(meal: meal))
                        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the code of FoodListRowView**

```
struct FoodListRowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: FoodListRowViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color(red: 237/255, green: 239/255, blue: 241/255))
                .frame(width: 250, height: 320, alignment: .center)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5, x: 0, y: -0.01)
            
            VStack() {
                Image("\(self.viewModel.meal.imageName)")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 220, alignment: .top)
                
                
                RatingView(rating: .constant(4))
                
                Text("\(self.viewModel.meal.name)")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                Text("\(self.viewModel.meal.price)$")
                
            }.frame(width: 250, height: 320, alignment: .top)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is code for FoodListRowViewModel

```
class FoodListRowViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var meal: Meal
    
    init(meal: Meal) {
        self.meal = meal
    }
}
```

Comment: You have many missing dependencies. Try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @pawello2222 cleared some things up, Thank you for taking the time to help me out. Really appreciate it

Comment: Is there a reason why did you use tuples? Do your categories need to be ordered?

Comment: I looked at tuples and dictionaries to be honest, there wasn't a reason in particular, down the line i see my categories being ordered in alphabetical order or by user preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can change your model from a tuple to a dictionary.  This way your meals can be easily grouped by category.

```
var mealCategories = [String: [Meal]]()
```

Also, as your `Meal` structs have already the `category` field, you can populate `mealCategories` in a loop:

```
meals.forEach { meal in
    mealCategories[meal.category, default: []].append(meal)
}
```

Note that as dictionaries in Swift are unordered you may want to sort it.

```
struct FoodListView: View {
    ...
    var body: some View {
        let categories = Array(viewModel.mealCategories.keys).sorted() // sorted list of categories
        return NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { category in
                    VStack {
                        Text("\(category)")
                        self.categoryView(meals: self.viewModel.mealCategories[category, default: []])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the `category` view:

```
extension FoodListView {
    func categoryView(meals: [Meal]) -> some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(meals, id: \.id) { meal in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("meal")) {
                        FoodListRowView(viewModel: FoodListRowViewModel(meal: meal))
                            .padding()
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough, your solution is elegant and simple. Thank you x10000 for your help, it worked to perfection.